# Make label color on TextInputLayout difference than editText hint text color

Tags: android, android-studio

Can I make label text color on TextInputLayout different than the editText hint text color

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutMargin16"
                android:textColorHint="@color/green"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/textLayoutInputSize">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutMargin16"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/blueColorButton"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I have this code however `android:textColorHint="@color/blueColorButton"`
how to set text color for it (different color than the TextInputLayoutlabel)
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jRaD.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwD8e.png)

Answer (score 3):

> You need to set theme in **`TextInputLayout`.** I attach one example. I hope it 's works for you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
   android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
   <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorWhiteAlpha</item>
   <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_16sp</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorWhite</item>
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhiteAlpha</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorWhiteAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/colorWhiteAlpha</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/colorWhiteAlpha</item>
</style>
```